# Plot overrides axes property 'XTick'

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-guide

I am creating a GUI in Matlab. I have several axes in which I plot different graphs. I have set in some of the axes the property `XTick` to `[]`. However, each time I plot a new graph in the same axes, the xticks appear again. I know I can delete them by using `set`:

```
set(handles.axes_0, 'XTick', []);
```

However, this creates a "flickering" effect: you see the ticks appearing and then dissapearing each time I plot something new.

Do you know how could I have an axes with the XTick disabled avoiding the flickering effect?

Some basic code:

```
figure(1); %create new figure
set(gca, 'XTick', []); %Disable xtick
plot([1 2 ], [2, 3]); %Plot something. Xtick appears again
set(gca, 'XTick', []); %Disable xtick until next plot
```

Comment: why don't you wait till the ery end of all plotting and then disable the ticks?

Comment: What I do is I draw a window of the signal (60 seconds), but when the user clics a slidebar, I plot another window (the following or the previous one). And that is when you can see the xticks appearing and disappearing again.

Comment: bugger the users... can't you get a different one?

Comment: A different user who doesn't use the slidebar?

Comment: perhaps, or one who is less annoyed by the ticking of the XTicks...

Comment: I'm afraid it will be much easier to change the program than the users :( No ideas in that direction?

Comment: setting `axis off` will do any good?

Comment: No, it doesn't. When I plot again, no changes :(

Comment: when `hold on` I do not see the ticking - this might be a lead for a solution.

Comment: Nice hint. I have made it work!! I do: h = findobj(handles.axes_0,'Type','line');
         if ~isempty(h)
             delete(h);  hold on; plot(x,y); hold off; This way I remove the previous line and plot the new one with hold on. If you post this as an answer, I will gladly accept it :)
         end

Comment: go ahead and post it yourself as your own answer. you did the work! I'll upvote you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650828/plot-overrides-axes-property-xtick#comment23954323_16650828) pointed out in a comment, when using `hold on` the ticks don't reappear. As I want to clean the previous plot before drawing the new one, I search for its identifier using `findobj` and then delete it. Finally, I draw the new plot with `hold on`. Example (suppose the axes handle is called handles.axes_0):

```
 h = findobj(handles.axes_0,'Type','line');
 if ~isempty(h)
    delete(h);
 end
 hold on
 plot(handles.axes_0,x,y);
 hold off
```